# $elemMatch Projection on a Simple Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Imagine a collection of movies (stored in a MongoDB collection), with each one looking something like this:

```
{ 
    _id: 123456,
    name: 'Blade Runner',
    buyers: [1123, 1237, 1093, 2910]
}
```

I want to get a list of movies, each one with an indication whether buyer 2910 (for example) bought it.

Any ideas?

I know I can change [1123, 1237, 1093, 2910] to [{id:1123}, {id:1237}, {id:1093}, {id:2910}] to allow the use of $elemMatch in the projection, but would prefer not to touch the structure.

I also know I can perhaps use the $unwind operator (within the aggregation framework), but that seems very wasteful in cases where buyer has thousands of values (basically exploding each document into thousands of copies in memory before matching).

Any other ideas? Am I missing something really simple here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$setIsSubset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset) aggregation operator to do this:

```js
var buyer = 2910;
db.movies.aggregate(
    {$project: {
        name: 1,
        buyers: 1,
        boughtIt: {$setIsSubset: [[buyer], '$buyers']}
    }}
)
```

That will give you all movie docs with a `boughtIt` field added that indicates whether `buyer` is contained in the the movie's `buyers` array.

This operator was added in MongoDB 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure of your intent here, but you don't need to change the structure just to use [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) in projection. You can just issue like this:

```js
db.movies.find({},{ "buyers": { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": 2910 } } })
```

That would filter the returned array elements to just the "buyer" that was indicated, or nothing where this was not present. It is true to point out that the `$eq` operator used here is not actually documented, but it does exist. So that may not be immediately clear that you can construct a condition in that way.

It seems a little wasteful to me though as you are returning "everything" regardless of whether the "buyer" is present or not. So a "query" seems more logical than a projection:

```js
db.movies.find({ "buyers": 2910 })
```

And optionally either just keeping only that matched result:

```js
db.movies.find({ "buyers": 2910 },{ "buyers.$": 1})
```

[Set operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/) in the aggregation framework give you more options with [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) which can do more to alter the document. But if you just want to know if someone "bought" the item, then a "query" seems the be logical and fastest way to do so.